# ChangeDisplaySettingsEx() always returns DISP_CHANGE_BADPARAM

Tags: c++, winapi

I am attempting to set the Display Mode of my Monitor using WinAPI C++ functions.

**My Problem:** Calling `ChangeDisplaySettingsEx()` always returns `DISP_CHANGE_BADPARAM`. What am I doing wrong?

I think it may be my devMode.dmDriverExtra value thats causing the error. I've read MSDN and the explaination of devMode.dmDriverExtra is confusing. What is it and how do I find out the Monitors' dmDriverExtra?

Whats causing my code below to always return `DISP_CHANGE_BADPARAM`?

```
DEVMODE devMode;
POINTL p                = {0,0};
_tcscpy(devMode.dmDeviceName, _T("\\Device\\00000072")); 
devMode.dmSpecVersion   = DM_SPECVERSION;
devMode.dmDriverVersion = 1;  // How do I determine the driver version?
devMode.dmSize          = sizeof(DEVMODE);
devMode.dmDriverExtra   = 0x5c0000; // 
devMode.dmFields        = DM_POSITION;
devMode.dmPosition      = p;

LONG res = ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(_T("\\Device\\00000072"), &devMode, mainHwnd, 0, NULL);
_tprintf(_T("%s: %d\n\n\n"), _T("\\Device\\00000072"), res); 
// The above printf always prints out "\Device\00000072: -5" (DISP_CHANGE_BADPARAM=-5)
```

Comment: directories should be `\\Device\\00000072`

Comment: `_tcscpy(devMode.dmDeviceName, _T("\Device\00000072"));` is instant memory corruption – `devMode` is uninitialized.

Comment: @ildjarn How do I set the devMode.dmDeviceName then?

Comment: @billz thanks. I changed that, although still the same error code returned so its still failing

Answer (score 1):

The hwnd parameter is documented to be reserved and must be NULL. Additionally dmDriverExtra is a 16 bit value, so 0x5c0000 doesn't fit.